# If string statement

Tags: c++, string, if-statement

I have a problem with the following code:

```
int main(){

    string name;
    cout<<"Enter: ";
    cin>>name;
    if(name == "AHAH"||"AHAH"||"ADAD"||"ACAC"||"ASAS"||"AHAD"||"AHAC"||"AHAS"||"ADAH"||"ADAC"\
        ||"ADAS"||"ACAH"||"ACAD"||"ACAS"||"ASAH"||"ASAD"||"ASAC"){
        cout<<"Call! Good hand!";
    }
    else if(name == "2H2H")
        cout<<"Rase";

system("pause");
};
```

No matter what I input the program outputs:

```
Call! Good hand!
```

What's the problem?

Comment: That's not how operator `||` works.

Comment: I would suggest implementing your pause inside your program and not using `system("pause")`, which is a fairly expensive operation in comparison.

Comment: I'm not sure why the minus nazi downvoted your post, but it wouldn't hurt to make your question clearer. Maybe "Value passed to conditional always produces same results." Even that sounds vague, though.

Comment: @labyrinth Most likey Lannser is a novice programmer, and might not even know to use those words yet :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write your if statement like so:

```
if ( name == "AHAH" || name == "ABCD" || ...etc... )
{
    cout << "Call, good hand!";
}
else if ( name == "2H2H" )
{
    cout << "Rase";
}
```

When you write your if statement like you did, you create pointers to char and since the char * is not NULL it has a value that is non-zero and therefore evaluates as True.

Answer (score 4):

When you have so many variants to compare with it could be better to keep them in container and then use algorithm or loop to compare:

```
std::set<std::string> names { "AHAH", "AHAH", "ADAD", "ACAC", 
                              "ASAS", "AHAD", "AHAC", "AHAS",
                              "ADAH", "ADAC" };
if( names.count( name ) )
     cout<<"Call! Good hand!";
```

or vector:

```
std::vector<std::string> names { "AHAH", "AHAH", "ADAD", "ACAC", 
                                 "ASAS", "AHAD", "AHAC", "AHAS",
                                 "ADAH", "ADAC" };
if( std::find( names.begin(), names.end(), name ) != names.end() ) 
    cout<<"Call! Good hand!";
```

The thing is that most probably you will need this list of names again anyway (when you write a real program that does something usefull)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that

```
if (name == "AHAH" || "ADAD"..)
```

Does not mean if name equals "AHAH" OR name equals "ADAD" but if (name == "AHAH") OR "ADAD". The latter is a `char *` implicitly converted to `bool`. Since the pointer is not null converts always to true. Hence the result.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
if(name == "AHAH" || "ADAD" ...
```

You want something like:

```
if((name == "AHAH") || (name == "ADAD") ...
```

Comment: || has higher priority over == so brackets there are not really necessary.

Comment: They are not there for precedence.  They are there for readability.

Comment: It might just be the way my brain works, but I find it easier to parse quickly with the parentheses.